# Angular 6 HttpClient response is returning Undefined

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular6

I created this auth-api.ts service, having a login method:

```
login(username, password)
  {
    let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders();
    headerOptions.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');


    const httpParams = new HttpParams()
      .set('username', username)
      .set('password', password);

    return this.http.post('http://dev.local/scripts/login.php', httpParams,  {
      headers: headerOptions
    }).pipe(map(
        res=>{
          console.log('user '+res)
        },
        err=>
          console.log(err)
      ))
  }
```

On button click, this method will be called inside login.component.ts using this method:

```
login(){
    const user = this.loginGroup.get('username').value;
    const pass = this.loginGroup.get('password').value;

    this.auth.login(user, pass).subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        this.loginGroup.reset();
      },
      (error)=>{
        console.log(error)
      }
    )
  }
```

The problem is that the `console.log(res)` from the api login method is returning the value, but the `console.log(data) from the second login method is returning undefined.

What I want is to make some conditions on `data`, so that's why I can't.

[image]

Comment: If you press f12 in chrome and type console.log(console.log("anything here")) you will see the same behaviour. I suspect it's because your data in this case, is literally the console.log().

Comment: So how can actually get the original value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the pipe. You are mapping your response to console.log() which is why you are getting undefined in your component.

Also you can handle the error from the component.

```
login(username, password)
  {
    let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders();
    headerOptions.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');


const httpParams = new HttpParams()
  .set('username', username)
  .set('password', password);

return this.http.post('http://dev.local/scripts/login.php', httpParams,  {
  headers: headerOptions
});
}
```

In simple words, Pipe is used to transform your output. Here map operator maps your response to a method or some expression to get the required input. If suppose your response returns 2, then if I do,

`map(response => response * 2)`,

your component will get data as 4 in subscribe method. I suggest you google for more information.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can you explain more what pipe and map do in this case ? I always use them but don't understand them too much.

Comment: Added explanation in answer

Answer (score 4):

If you want to return and log the result in console use `tap` operator instead of `map`

```
return this.http.post('http://dev.local/scripts/login.php', httpParams,  {
  headers: headerOptions
}).pipe(tap(
    res=>{
      console.log('user '+res)
    },
    err=>
      console.log(err)
  ))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**try this**

let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return this.http.post('http://dev.local/scripts/login.php',httpParams,  { headers: this.headers }).toPromise();
```